# Dynamic Table from Lotus Notes to XPages within a form

Tags: xpages

I am taking an existing Lotus Notes database and converting to Xpages.  There is one of those tables containing 3 multi-value fields, with New Line as the seperator and the "Add New", "Modify" and "Delete" buttons controlling how the data is entered and removed.  The customer would like the XPage to look as similar to the Notes GUI as possible, and I was thinking I would use the dijit dialog box to do the add new line and figure out the delete and modify.  But from what I can tell, the dialog box can only be used on client-side and the data input into the dialog box can't be brought down onto the Xpage.  Is this true?  I was thinking I would use an editable field within a repeat, but I also couldn't that working properly.

Basically, it the solution has to show the multi-value fields for past documents and also be able to allow users to edit those older document...plus work similar/exactly the way as in the past when creating new docs.

Thanks in advance for any help I can get on this as it seems a ton easier than I am probably making it out to be.

I just wanted to update after the solution below, which appears to be an excellent way to solve this problem.  However, as an admitted XPages novice, I am really struggling with the application of this concept.  This is what I have, and it obviously isn't working.

Logically, this sounds like a great solution.  However, I am no xpages expert and I simply can't get this working properly even to get started.  Anything at all that would make this easier for me to even get started would be a big help.  I'm not one to usually look for "the answer"...I'm just having difficulty getting a handle on this Multi-value field table issue. Thanks again in advance...here's what I wrote that is coming up with a 500 error.  "A" is the multi-value field name.

```
<xp:table>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="rowdata">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getItemValue("A")}]]></xp:this.value>
                <xp:tr id="valueRow">
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:text
                            value="#{javascript: return rowdata[i]}" />
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false"
                        refreshMode="partial" execMode="partial" execId="valueRow"
                        immediate="true">
                        <xp:this.action>
                            <![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getItemValue("A")}]]>
                        </xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:repeat>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
</xp:table>
```

Comment: I think that a repeat control would be the better option. You can customize the look and feel to more closely match the old system, add the buttons and make the fields link to access the actual documents.

Comment: NotesIn9 did a tutorial, similar to this. Here is the link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwTNARkKDAQ

Answer (score 2):

I would say do the following

1. Create a repeat control which will extract the data from the multi value fields and print them read only. The repeat control will generate a tr structure with a event handler bound to it on the onclick event. something like this:

[image]

2 In the onclick event change the style of the tr clientside (using dojo) so people know they selected that row and set the id / identifier of that row in a scoped var

3 Above the repeat control add controls like add, remove, update. The add and update will open a dialog box and will read the data from the selected row ( or none if its a add action). The delete control will remove the data from the multiline value fields, save the document and refres the repeat control.

This should work.

Comment: I added some comments to my original question above.  Thanks for the help but I'm still struggling so far with the concept and application of your excellent suggestion.